Compute $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\arctan\left(\cos(x)\right)\ dx$
I have to compute $$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos(x)\arctan\left(\cos(x)\right)\ dx$$
This is my attempt to solve it.
First, I integrate using integration by parts:
$$f(x)=\arctan\left(\cos(x)\right) \Longrightarrow f'(x)=\frac{-\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}$$
$$g'(x)\ dx=\cos(x) \Longrightarrow g(x)=\sin(x)$$
So, I have that:
$$I=\Bigl[\sin(x)\arctan\left(\cos(x)\right)\Bigl]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}+\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx=$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx=(\ast)$$
Now, I use the following trigonometric identities:
$$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}, \quad \quad \cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$
and, substituting them in the integral, I obtain:
$$(\ast)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{3+\cos(2x)}\ dx=(\spadesuit)$$
Now, I proceed with the following substitutions:
$$t=\tan(x) \Longrightarrow dx=\frac{dt}{1+t^2}, \quad \quad \cos(2x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
Therefore, I have:
$$(\spadesuit)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{3+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} \cdot \frac{dt}{1+t^2}=$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_0^\sqrt{3} \frac{t^2}{(2+t^2)(1+t^2)}\ dt=(\clubsuit)$$
Now, I use simple fracs:
$$\frac{t^2}{(2+t^2)(1+t^2)}=\frac{At+B}{2+t^2}+\frac{Ct+D}{1+t^2}=[...]=\frac{2}{2+t^2}-\frac{1}{1+t^2}$$
and then:
$$(\clubsuit)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\int_0^\sqrt{3} \frac{1}{2\left(1+\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\right)}\ dt-\int_0^\sqrt{3}\frac{1}{1+t^2}\ dt=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{2}\Bigl[\arctan\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\Bigl]_0^\sqrt{3}-\Bigl[\arctan\left(t\right)\Bigl]_0^\sqrt{3}=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{2}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{3}$$
Is it correct? Is there some trick with which to simplify the calculations a bit? I think I have used all the possible integration techniques and maybe there is a way to reduce the calculations. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

you can proceed with tangent sub right after IBP

\begin{align}\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cos^2x}&=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{1+\cos^2x}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}}{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}+1}\times \frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 x}}{2+\tan^2x}\times \frac{1}{\cos^2x}\&=\frac{\tan^2 x}{(2+\tan^2x)(1+\tan^2 x)}\times \frac{1}{\cos^2x}\end{align}

Nice, definitely saves some substitutions!

Via integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \cos x \arctan (\cos x) d x 
= & \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \arctan (\cos x) d(\sin x) \\
= & {[\sin x \arctan (\cos x)]_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \sin x \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos ^2 x} d t } \\
= & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \arctan \frac{1}{2}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{1+\cos ^2 x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Multiplying both the numerator and denominator of the last integrand by $\sec^4x$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sin ^2 x}{1+\cos ^2 x} d x=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sec ^2 x \tan ^2 x}{\sec ^2x(1+\sec ^2 x)} d x \\
= & \int_0^{\sqrt{3}} \frac{t^2}{\left(t^2+1\right)\left(t^2+2\right)} d t , \quad  \text { where } t=\tan x \\
= & \int_0^{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{2}{t^2+2}-\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right) d t \\
= & {\left[\sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\tan ^{-1} t\right]_0^{\sqrt{3}} \\ =  \sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1 }\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{3}} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps.

Alternatively,$$\frac{\sin^2x}{1+\cos^2x}=\frac{2\sec^2x}{2+\tan^2x}-1$$

what a good suggestion ! Thank you.

Not the shortest way - just for the pleasure of using complex numbers.
$$I=\int\frac{\sin ^2 (x)}{1+\cos ^2 (x)}\, d x$$ Using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$I=\int \frac{4 t^2}{\left(t^2+1\right)\left(t^4+1\right)} \,dt=2\int \frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}\,dt-2\int \frac{1}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$2\,\frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}=2\frac{ t^2+1}{(t^2+i)(t^2-i)}=\frac{1-i}{t^2-i}+\frac{1+i}{t^2+i}$$
$$2\int \frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}\,dt=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\log
   \left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4}+t}{(-1)^{1/4}-t}\right)+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\log\left(\frac{(-1)^{3/4}+t}{(-1)^{3/4}-t}\right)$$
$$2\int \frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}\,dt=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \log \left(\frac{t^2+i \sqrt{2} t-1}{t^2-i \sqrt{2} t-1}\right)$$ Using the logarithmic representation of the arctangent
$$2\int \frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}\,dt=\sqrt{2} \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(1+t\sqrt{2} \right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(1-t\sqrt{2} \right)\right)$$
$$2\int \frac{ t^2+1}{t^4+1}\,dt=\sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t\sqrt{2} }{1-t^2}\right)$$

A bit faster for the whole antiderivative.
$$I=\int \cos(x)\arctan\left(\cos(x)\right)\, dx$$
$$\cos(x)=t \quad \implies \quad I=-\int \frac{t }{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\tan ^{-1}(t)\,dt$$
Integration by parts
$$I=\sqrt{1-t^2}\, \tan ^{-1}(t)-\int \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t^2+1}\,dt$$
$$t=\frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2+1}} \quad \implies \quad J=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t^2+1}\,dt=\int\frac{dv}{\left(v^2+1\right)\left(2v^2+1\right)}$$
Partial fraction decomposition
$$J=2\int \frac{dv}{2 v^2+1}\,dv-\int\frac{dv}{v^2+1}\,dv$$


Yet another method, but here we first try to remove the unpleasant $\cos{x}$ inside the arctangent.

$t = \cos{x} \implies x = \arccos{t}\,, \, dx = -\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$
$$\therefore \int_{0}^{\pi/3}{\cos{x}\cdot\arctan{(\cos{x})} dx} \,\,\xrightarrow{t \, = \, \cos{x}}\,\,  \int_{1/2}^{1}{\frac{t\cdot\arctan{t}}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}dt}$$
See that $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[ \sqrt{1 - t^2} \right] = \dfrac{-t}{\sqrt{1- t^2}}$ and so consider $\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[ \sqrt{1 - t^2} \cdot \arctan{t} \right] = \dfrac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}{1 + t^2}-\dfrac{t\cdot\arctan{t}}{\sqrt{1- t^2}}$.
$$\rightarrow \int{d \left[ \sqrt{1 - t^2} \cdot \arctan{t} \right]} = \int{\dfrac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}{1 + t^2}dt}-\int{\dfrac{t\cdot\arctan{t}}{\sqrt{1- t^2}}dt}
\\\therefore\int_{1/2}^{1}{\dfrac{t\cdot\arctan{t}}{\sqrt{1- t^2}}dt} = \int_{1/2}^{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}{1 + t^2}dt} - \left[ \sqrt{1 - t^2} \cdot \arctan{t} \right]_{1/2}^{1}$$

Forenote: $\displaystyle \int{\dfrac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}{1 + t^2}dt}$ is easier to evaluate by trig substitution. However, I will avoid trig substitution otherwise it is no different to Lai's answer.

Use Euler's third substitution; set $t = \dfrac{1 - u^2}{1 + u^2}$.
$$\int_{1/2}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}{1 + t^2}}dt \to \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}/{3}}{\frac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)(1+u^4)}}du
\\= \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}/{3}}{\frac{1}{1 - \sqrt{2}u + u^2} + \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{2}u + u^2} - \frac{2}{1 + u^2}}du
\\= \sqrt{2}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} + 1\right)} + \sqrt{2}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} - 1\right)} - \frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$\therefore\int_{1/2}^{1}{\dfrac{t\cdot\arctan{t}}{\sqrt{1- t^2}}dt} = \sqrt{2}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} + 1\right)} + \sqrt{2}\arctan{\left(\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} - 1\right)} - \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\arctan{\frac{1}{2}}$$

